# How to get buttons to size full width, responsively

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue trying to get the green buttons underneath the header to lay properly across devices. Full desktop is fine, but as the screen gets smaller, the buttons will break between words and go the next line. And on mobile, I'd like them to stack, but they overlap, and I'm trying to add a bottom/top margin, but nothing helps.

http://www.cooldownjuice.com/collections/menu

How can I get this to lay properly?

Here's my code. (added max/min width as suggested on another topic here)

```
.catbtn {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    background-color: #319E15;
    color: #fff!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #319E15;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: To stack the buttons you should use float property.

Comment: Thanks everyone! You all gave me some good stuff to try out. It's looking good :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use float, like so

```
.catbn {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Also I personally believe the behavior is better when you remove `width: 100%` but that's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
display: -webkit-inline-box;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px,
```

And voilà! And you can maintain your center buttons. If you wish, you can float:left/right to align

Answer (score 0):

To avoid breaking of words and overlapping buttons, add following rules in your css

```
.catbn{
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
    /*Rest of the css*/
 }
```

Comment: This is a good solution, also tend to think it looks better on large screens without width:100%, so possibly adding a media query to adjust this property to be true only once stacking begins...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to set the `a` to block. You may use `float` or `display:inline-block`

Here is your modified code for button.

```
.catbtn {
padding: 10px;
margin-right: 4px;
margin-left: 7px;
background-color: #319E15;
color: #fff!important;
text-decoration: none!important;
font-family: Lato;
font-size: 100%;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 2px solid #319E15;
width: 100%;
min-width: 50px;
display: inline-block;/* a as block and inline*/
max-width: 174px; /* Set the width*/
}
```

Hope this help you.!